# If $f' (x) = c$, a constant, for all $x$, show that $f(x) = cx + d$ for some constant $d$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

If $f' (x) = c$, a constant, for all $x$, show that $f(x) = cx +
d$ for some constant $d$.

By the limit definition $\lim_{x_0 \to 0} \frac{f(x+x_0)-f(x_0)}{x_0} = c$.

How can I get that the function is linear? I don't know about integrals yet and can't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f'(x)$. We know that $F(x)$ and $f(x)$ differ by only a constant. Therefore:

$$f(x) = F(x) + d$$

for some constant $d$.

Take the derivative of $cx$. If you get $c$, then you know that $F(x) = cx$ is *an* antiderivative of $f'(x)$. Thus, you have $f(x) = F(x)+d = cx+d$.

This uses the definition of antiderivative, not but does not actually calculate an integral. If you have not yet learned that any two antiderivatives of a function may differ by at most a constant, then this answer is not sufficient, of course. The proof of this involves the Mean Value Theorem. So, any answer will depend greatly on what you have already learned.

If you must use the Mean Value Theorem, then suppose you have two functions $F(x), G(x)$ such that $F'(x) = G'(x) = f'(x)$. In other words, $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are both antiderivatives of $f'(x)$.

Define $H(x) = F(x) - G(x)$.

Then $H'(x) = F'(x) - G'(x) = f'(x)-f'(x) = 0$ is identically zero for all $x$.

Let $a<b$ be any arbitrary real numbers. Then by the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $H(b)-H(a) = H'(c)(b-a) = 0(b-a) = 0$ shows that $H(b)-H(a)=0$ for all $a,b$, so $H$ is a constant function.

Thus, any two antiderivatives of a function differ by at most a constant.

Comment: Can I use the same strategy with Mean Value Theorem (MVT) to reach some conclusion about the difference of $f$ and $g$ if $f'(x) = g'(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, for some interval? For example, following you, take $H(x) = f(x) - g(x)$, $H'(x) = f'(x) - g'(x)  = 0$, $H(x_1)-H(x_0) = H'(x)(x_1-x_0) = 0,  f(x_1) - g(x_1) - f(x_0) + g(x_0) = 0$ $f(x_1) - f(x_0) = g(x_1) - g(x_0) $. I am not sure if this statement has any meaning (like with the equal changes of arguments the values of functions changes equally?).

Comment: I am being a little cavalier with the use of the Mean Value Theorem. I am assuming that $H(x)$ is continuous and differentiable on every interval. This is because it is the difference of two functions which are both differentiable. I am not sure if you have proven this yet, but differentiability implies continuity, so the fact that these functions are differentiable implies they are continuous, and the sum (or difference) of differentiable functions are continuous and differentiable. Thus, this works over any interval of the Reals. Since I chose $a,b$ arbitrarily, it works over all reals.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-cx$. Then $g’(x)=f’(x)-c=c-c=0$.

Therefore $g$ is constant, say $g(x)=d$.

Then $f(x)=cx+d$.